# Linux software RAID: Is a disk faulty?

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid5

I have a setup with three identical harddrives, recognized as sdb, sdd and sde. I have one RAID0 partition (md0) and two RAID5 partitions (md1 and md2) across these three disks. All my RAID partitions appear to be working normally, and have done so since I created them. I have seen messages on the console about md[12] being "active with 2 out of 3 devices", which to me sounds like a problem.

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid0] [linear] [multipath] [raid1] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid0 sdb3[0] sdd3[1] sde3[2]
      24574464 blocks super 1.2 512k chunks

md1 : active raid5 sdd2[1] sde2[3]
      5823403008 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]

md0 : active raid5 sdd1[1] sde1[3]
      20462592 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I'm not experienced with mdadm, but this to me seems like arrays md[12] are missing the sdb disk. However, md2 does not seems to be missing anything. So, has the sdb disk failed or is this just some configuration issue? Any more diagnostics I need to do to figure that out?

EDIT:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2:
         Magic : a92b4efc
       Version : 1.2
   Feature Map : 0x0
    Array UUID : 94d56562:90a999e8:601741c0:55d8c83f
          Name : jostein1:1  (local to host jostein1)
 Creation Time : Sat Aug 18 13:00:00 2012
    Raid Level : raid5
  Raid Devices : 3
Avail Dev Size : 5823404032 (2776.82 GiB 2981.58 GB)
    Array Size : 5823403008 (5553.63 GiB 5963.16 GB)
 Used Dev Size : 5823403008 (2776.82 GiB 2981.58 GB)
   Data Offset : 262144 sectors
  Super Offset : 8 sectors
  Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
         State : active
   Device UUID : cee60351:c3a525ce:a449b326:6cb5970d

   Update Time : Tue May 24 21:43:20 2016
      Checksum : 4afdc54a - correct
        Events : 7400

        Layout : left-symmetric
    Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)


# mdadm --examine /dev/sde2
/dev/sde2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 94d56562:90a999e8:601741c0:55d8c83f
           Name : jostein1:1  (local to host jostein1)
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 18 13:00:00 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 5823404032 (2776.82 GiB 2981.58 GB)
     Array Size : 5823403008 (5553.63 GiB 5963.16 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5823403008 (2776.82 GiB 2981.58 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9c5abb6d:8f1eecbd:4b0f5459:c0424d26

    Update Time : Tue Oct 11 21:17:10 2016
       Checksum : a3992056 - correct
         Events : 896128

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

So --examine on sdb shows it is active, while the same command on sdd and sde show it as missing.

```
# mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 18 13:00:00 2012
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 5823403008 (5553.63 GiB 5963.16 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2911701504 (2776.82 GiB 2981.58 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Oct 11 22:03:50 2016
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : jostein1:1  (local to host jostein1)
           UUID : 94d56562:90a999e8:601741c0:55d8c83f
         Events : 897492

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       50        1      active sync   /dev/sdd2
       3       8       66        2      active sync   /dev/sde2
```

EDIT2:

The event count for the device no longer part of the array is very different from the others:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[bde]1 | egrep 'Event|/dev/sd'
/dev/sdb1:
         Events : 603
/dev/sdd1:
         Events : 374272
/dev/sde1:
         Events : 374272
```

Smartmontools for the disk that is not part of the array:

```
# smartctl -d ata -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-4.2.0-36-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green (AF, SATA 6Gb/s)
Device Model:     WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAWZ2185619
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25c58f89e
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Oct 12 18:54:30 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (51480) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 494) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   147   144   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       9641
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1398
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       7788
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1145
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       45
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       309782
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   124   103   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: check the logfiles

Comment: There are no errors in dmesg. Any other logs I should check?

Comment: `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb2`

Comment: Look at the SMART data for the failed drive?  smartctl. See if it is reporting as failed?

Comment: @Zoredache smartctl shows the drive is fine, as far as I can tell, see output as comment to the question. The output is very similar to other disks of the same type that work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mdstat` file says it all.

`[3/2] [_UU]` means that while there are 3 defined physical volumes, only 2 are in use at the moment. Similarly the `_UU` says the same.

For grater details on the raid devices (before going to the physical ones) you'd run (as root)

```
mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md0
mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md1
mdadm --detail --verbose /dev/md2
```

On my system (using raid6) I have simulated a failure and this is an example output:

```
dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 29 09:51:41 2016
     Raid Level : raid6
     Array Size : 16764928 (15.99 GiB 17.17 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Oct 11 13:06:50 2016
          State : clean   <<== CLEAN!
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
           UUID : 3837ba75:eaecb6be:8ceb4539:e5d69538
         Events : 43

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1  <<== NEW ENTRY
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1

       0       8        1        -      faulty   /dev/sda1  <<== SW-REPLACED
```

Comment: So I have "state: clean, degraded" in the middle and "removed" for the listing of disk number 0 (which I assume should have been sdb). Can I recover from "removed" somehow? The full output has been included in the question.

Comment: @josteinb You'd add spare devices so the RAID can be automatically reconstruced. This is my current setup, as I showed in the answer.

Comment: @josteinb By the way, I prefer to 1) create a RAID device over entire disks, 2) then partition (and 3) then LVM eveything). You first did partitioning, then the RAID. My starting point is: does that make any sense to you? When a drive is gone, then all partitions are (supposed to be) gone as well.

Comment: I see your point about raid first, partitioning second. It is a long time since I created this setup, but I would think the reason why I partitioned first is that I have one raid0 and two raid5 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

md1 and md2 are raid5 arrays, degraded because their respective partitions on /dev/sdb are failed or marked falty. Run mdadm --examine on the array itself for more details (madam --examine /dev/md1).

If all is well with /dev/sdb, re-add the partitions to the arrays. Get the correct partition numbers from your /etc/mdadm.conf or the output of --examine on the array.

mdadm --re-add /dev/sdb[?] /dev/md1

Comment: I tried this, --re-add does not work. mdadm just responded that the device could not be re-added. It may be related to the event counts shown in EDIT2 of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2` was kicked from `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1` respectively. You can doing `grep` on your syslogs (`/var/log/messages*` on the RHEL/CentOS/etc based distros, `/var/log/syslog*` on the Debian/Ubuntu based distros) to find what has caused this if these are still kept.

To fix this now, first thing I suggest you to issue a SMART test on the /dev/sdb. This can be done with `smartctl -t long /dev/sdb` (this is a non-destructive test) and then you can check both it's progress and results with `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`.

If everything looks to be fine with the disk afterwards, you can re-add partitions to the RAID arrays which might cause rebuilds (and most likely will), which is still non-destructive:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdb2
```

You can watch rebuild progress by issuing `watch cat /proc/mdstat` command (which will print /proc/mdstat every 2 seconds on screen).

If you didn't had write-intent bitmap before, I strongly suggest to add it after rebuild:

```
mdadm -G /dev/mdX -b internal
```

Replace X with your array number. Proceed for every array you have active. It doesn't takes much space, and is non-destructive too. But it helps with data consistency and rebuild speed sometimes.